# how to create a view from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with getting combined records from 3 tables.

Here is the structure of the tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adds` (
`addid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`addtypeid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`addcreatedon` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`addtitle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`addtext` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`addid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adds_filters` (
`addfilterid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`addid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`filterid` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`addfilterid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories_filters` (
`filterid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`catid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`filtername` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`sorder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`visible` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`filterid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=230 ;
```

Adds have one to many relationship with adds_filters. That is, one add can have more then one filter.

What I need is the following:

I would like to create a view which when select * would return all rows from adds, together with filterid(s) and respective filtername(s). Please note that one add may have many filterid(s)

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards

Comment: Are you familiar with JOINS? That's your solution.

Comment: I make numerous attempts with different kind of joins without any luck so far. So i thought that creating a view might be much better idea. However i have no idea how to create such a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a view.

I think you want to use a combination of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`. That way you will get 1 result for each row in the `adds` table, along with a list of related filter_ids and filter_names, if any.

Something like this:

```
select adds.addid, adds.addtypeid, adds.addcreatedon, adds.addtitle, adds.addtext,
  group_concat(adds_filters.filterid) as filter_ids, 
  group_concat(categories.filtername) as filter_names
from adds
  left outer join adds_filters on adds_filters.addid = adds.addid
  left outer join categories_filters on categories_filters.filterid = adds_filters.filterid
group by adds.addid, adds.addtypeid, adds.addcreatedon, adds.addtitle, adds.addtext;
```

Comment: Hi, i get the following error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'ai.inst_name' in 'field list'. Which field should be here?

Comment: Sorry about that! I used an old query of mine as a template and missed two of the replacements. It's fixed now. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

```
create view v1 as
select adds.addid as addid, categories_filters.filtername as filtername, categories_filters.filterid as filterid  
from adds inner join adds_filters on adds.addid = adds_filters.addid
inner join categories_filters on categories_filters.filterid = adds_filters.filterid
```

Comment: I get the following error when I attempt to execute the sql: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'addid'

Comment: Please see my edits. You need to explicitly mention the column names. I added two columns. You can add more columns if you wish.

Comment: This view produces the same results as: FROM `adds` AS a
INNER JOIN `adds_filters` AS af ON a.addid = af.addid
LIMIT 0 , 30 `   What i need is all filterid(s) for the specific addid in the same row. I don't know if that is possible...

Comment: You may need to use left/right outer join instead of inner join. If you explain what do you want by example then I can help more. Also see my edit (I added filter id column)